# Seamlessly play video files in sequence with HTML <video>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have tried several methods:

1. I tried to create hidden video tags and show/hide them, but this will cause flickering.
2. I tried to change the src attribute of the video, but I have to call load() method before play(), and the load() will load the new video.

   This is not what I want either, because this causes the new video to stop for a while (because need time to load).
3. I tried to cache the new video by using ajax to load the new video in background before the previous video is finished. The new video can be downloaded completely (300Kbytes) before the old video is finished.

   But when I call .load() function on the new video, it will be downloaded again.

My question is: for my third method, is there a way for the video object to make use of the downloaded file in cache?

After reading around, I think the above three are probably the only ways to realize my objective. The third one is really what I want but the video file just got downloaded twice (once is Ajax download, and another is calling load()). Note that, without calling load(), just simply changing the src attribute and calling play() will not work.

Comment: Why don't you set the src attribute as the cached video (maybe of the format data:video/mp4;..... something like that) and then call load ()

Comment: Hi, I am not aware how to access the cached file using javascript? For example, I use $.get("http://myvideo"), I am not aware where it is saved? Any hints? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could use var data; $.get ("myvideo").done (function (dat){data = dat;}); You get the idea right?

Comment: I tried save the data into a Blob, and create object URL from that blob, then load url from blob. The problem is that the .load function causes non trivial time, and causes even more flickering than replacing <video> tag. It seems that not possible to implement seamless transaction between videos (I am actually trying to implementing a live-video by fragmenting the live video into small video intervals and play them in real time consecutively).

Comment: To be more specific, for the replacing video tag method, the hidden video tag can call load when the old is still playing, so when call play and replace the old tag, it's more smooth (though flickering). However, if just replace src and call load on the buffered object, there's a significant delay.

Comment: You could start your second video before the first one ends based on the lag you get and as the first ends, hide it, leaving the second to play seamlessly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Media Source Extensions are what you need. It's hard to find good documentation on them yet (at the time of writing, [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource) is mostly stubs), but you can delve into [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/) if you dare.

The two-sentence summary is that with Media Source Extensions you can create a `MediaSource` object and set it as the source of a `<video>` element, instead of pointing the `<video>` at the URL of a complete video. Then you can use JavaScript to explicitly download videos representing further segments of your live stream and append them to your `MediaSource` object, and the segments will play seamlessly.

Also, while it's slightly beyond the scope of what you've asked here, [MPEG-DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) is a technique for doing *exactly what you're interested in* (i.e. streaming live video by encoding short segments as individual files, such as short standalone mp4s, and serving these segments individually to the browser). There's no way to implement MPEG-DASH in a browser without Media Source Extensions, so they are often discussed together. There are some good writeups (at different levels of detail) on building a DASH player with HTML and JavaScript using Media Source Extensions on [the BBC's tech blog](http://www.bbc.co.uk/rd/blog/2014/03/media-source-extensions) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn551368(v=vs.85).aspx).

Unfortunately, Media Source Extensions are not yet available in all major browsers. For instance, the latest version of Firefox on my Mac doesn't have `window.MediaSource`. This means you can't do segmented live streaming in a way that will work on all major browsers using only a HTML 5 `<video>` element *yet*. Unfortunately, it's still necessary to fall back to Flash if you need cross-browser compatibility.

Like you, I tried to implement this behaviour without using Media Source Extensions. I tried (and tried combining) a whole bunch of techniques, including swapping out URLs on `<video>` elements, unhiding and playing `<video>` elements, downloading segments fully in advance and storing them in [Blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) that I'd use as the `src` for my `<video>` elements, and setting the [`preload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-preload) attribute to `auto` to load the segments into memory in advance... but nothing worked. In Google Chrome, using *any* of these techniques results in a visible stutter when you `play()` the second video from the first video's `ended` event, even if you've loaded the second video fully in advance. There just isn't a way to get seamless consecutive video playback using `<video>` elements without some kind of stutter in browsers that don't support Media Source Extensions.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't read this. I have already found a solution (not perfect) by myself. The solution is: use video.js, and dynamically create video tags and swap them. Also, do not use the play_ended or similar events, use timer. For example, if you downloaded the video, get the video length (for me it's simple because each video is 0.8second), and I use a timer of 0.8s to swap. The flickering goes away. For synchronization, I use play rate, to make the video play faster or slower dynamically (set the timer accordingly too).

Comment: @user534498 hi, could you please share an example here? Thanks a lot

Comment: @user534498 I am looking to achieve something similar - multiple short video clips uploaded to a CMS. Then on specific pages, these can be selected in sequence to create a single conjoined video out of them that plays seamlessly. Since this original answer was made a while ago, do you have any updated thoughts?